# Why do I get non-object type 'char *(const char *, int) throw()' is not assignable

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5

I implemented a minimal verifiable example below that replicates the issue.
**The problem** I have is after that a `QLabel` count down arrives to `00:00`, I would like the application to shut down automatically. But this is not happening and I obtain from compiler the following error:

`non-object type 'char *(const char *, int) throw()' is not assignable`

Below the minimal verifiable example code
[image: cdw]

**mainwindow.h**

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTime>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QProcess>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    void stopAtZeroCountDown();

public slots:
    void timerUpdate();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTimer *timer;
    QTime time;
    QProcess *stopAtZero;
};
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    stopAtZeroCountDown();

    ui->countDown->setText("1:00");
    time.setHMS(0,1,0);
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerUpdate()));
    timer->start(1000);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::stopAtZeroCountDown()
{
    this->stopAtZero = new QProcess(this);
    this->stopAtZero->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    connect(this->stopAtZero, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished),
            [this](int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus){
            qDebug() << "[EXEC] FINISHED: " << exitCode << exitStatus;

            index = ui->countDown->setText("00:00"); // <-- Error here
            if(&index)
            {
              this->stopAtZero->start(QStringLiteral("/bin/sh"), QStringList() << QStringLiteral("/path/to/shutdown_executable.sh"));
            };
    });
}

void MainWindow::timerUpdate()
{
    time = time.addSecs(-1);
    ui->countDown->setText(time.toString("mm:ss"));
}
```

Below the compilation error, and also [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FSEp.png)

> ```
> /home/emanuele/catkin_docking_ws/src/lidarlauncher/src/lidarlauncher/mainwindow.cpp:
> In lambda function:
> /home/emanuele/catkin_docking_ws/src/lidarlauncher/src/lidarlauncher/mainwindow.cpp:113:40: error: could not convert
> ‘this->MainWindow::ui->Ui::MainWindow::<anonymous>.Ui_MainWindow::labelCountDown->QLabel::setNum(0)’
> from ‘void’ to ‘bool’
>            if(ui->labelCountDown->setNum(00))
> ```

**EDIT_2**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //ui->countDown->setText(time.toString("hh:mm:ss"));
    ui->countDown->setText("1:00");
    //ui->countDown->setText(time.toString("mm:ss"));
    time.setHMS(0,1,0);
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerUpdate()));
    timer->start(1000);

    connect(this->stopAtZero, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [this, script = this->stopAtZero](){
         QString s = QString::fromUtf8(script->readAll());
         qDebug() << "[EXEC] DATA: " << s;
         if (ui->countDown->setText("00:00")) { // <-- error here
             this->stopAtZero->start(QStringLiteral("/bin/sh"), QStringList() << QStringLiteral("/home/emanuele/catkin_docking_ws/src/lidarboatsproject/stop_lidar_deck_and_gui.sh"));             
         }
    });
}
```

So far I consulted the [following source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32313150/array-type-char-is-not-assignable) to help me solve the problem but without success.
I know that the problem is caused by an assignment that should be a `QString` as I am trying to capture the `00:00` format of the timer.

I also consulted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44618937/overwriting-function-pointer-raises-error-non-object-type-is-not-assignable), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328166/why-am-i-getting-the-expression-is-not-assignable-error) and those are all clear examples to me, with the only difference that here I am using qt components such as in this case a `QLabel`, it might be a simple error but I am getting a bit confused.

Thanks for pointing to the right direction for solving this issue.

Comment: Do you have a compilation error or you must run the program to get the error?

Comment: What is `index`? And whatever it is what do you think `if (&index)` is supposed to mean?

Comment: I am basically trying to catch the `00:00` of the countdown and if that is true, shutdown the application. With `index` I am trying to catch the `00:00`.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, yes I get a compilation error: I added the error on the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have some code that look like this:

If you read the [Qt documentation for `QLabel::setText`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#text-prop) correctly, you'll see that there is a problem with the code you presented.

The Qt documentation says that the `setText` returns `void`. In other words, that function return nothing.

Yet, you try to get the result of the function to test in the if statement:

```
//          call to setText
//  v-----------------------------v
if (ui->countDown->setText("00:00")) {
    // ...            
}
```

What the compiler sees is something like this:

```
if (/* expression that returns void */) {
    // ...            
}
```

This is not valid. You cannot do `if (void())`. What would it even do?

Whatever you're trying to test with this if statement, it will have to be done another way.

---

I will try to guess what you're trying to do for the following, so it may be less accurate.

My guess is that you're trying to test if the countdown is equal to `00:00` in order to shutdown. Let me help you there.

You want to execute something when the timer has finished. This should be done in your timer update member function:

```
void MainWindow::timerUpdate()
{
    time = time.addSecs(-1);
    ui->countDown->setText(time.toString("mm:ss"));

    // Check if we have a zero time on this tick
    if (time == QTime(0, 0)) {
        // put your code into the shutdown_function to make the shutdown
        shutdown_function();
    }
}
```

Here in each ticks, we test if the time is equal to a zero time. When it is, we proceed to execute the shutdown function.

Comment: Thanks your guess is 1001% correct! That was exactly what I was trying to do and your suggestion worked. Also thanks for pointing out that I was calling an empty statement. I understand what I was doing wrong! :) Thanks for your time. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**You forgot to declare `index` as a variable.**

There is a function `index` somewhere in scope and your compiler thinks you're trying to assign to it, which you can't do.

Furthermore, `if (&index)` makes no sense, as every variable that exists has a non-null address.

I suggest you review your library's documentation for `setText` to see what value it returns, and how to use that value… if it returns a value at all (which would be weird for a setter).

Comment: Hello and thanks for reading the question. I tried to modify according to your suggestion and things got a little better. I have a small error now. I added **EDIT_2** on the question showing what I did. I mostly acted on the constructor

Comment: I still don't see any declaration for a variable named `index`.

Comment: for the declaration initially I tried this: `auto index = ui->countDown->setText("00:00");` which gave me [this](https://i.imgur.com/B3efttb.png) that is why I tried to have an additional way

Comment: @Emanuele So that's saying `setText` has a return type of `void`, i.e. _it doesn't return anything_. What are you hoping that `index` will be? To re-iterate, you need to consult the documentation for this `setText` function to find out how to use it.

Comment: yes, basically catching when `setText` of the [QLabel](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlabel.html) is `00:00`, meaning when the count down arrives at 0 (or the index I am trying to catch). Then shutdown the application.

Comment: I set it to `00:00` because I was trying to hard-code the value to see if that is working, but still it does not.

Comment: Okay, then I'm really unclear on what you're trying to do. You need to read the documentation and some examples I think.